# magento want to edit "catalog category link" widget to display image of the specific category too

Tags: magento, widget, edit

magento want to edit "catalog category link" widget to display image of the specific category too.
i tried editing the 'category/widget/link/link_block.phtml'

```
<?php
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
?>
<span class="widget widget-category-link">
  <a <?php echo $this->getLinkAttributes() ?>>
    <span><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAnchorText()) ?></span>
    <img src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl();?>" />
  </a>
  <br/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Widget_Link` block. Follow below step to get category image in Widget:

1. Copy this file: `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link.php`
2. Past this file: `app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link.php`
3. Add below code into `app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link.php` file

   ```
   public function getImage(){
   $imgPath = '';
   if ($this->_entityResource) {

       $idPath = explode('/', $this->_getData('id_path'));
       if (isset($idPath[1])) {
           $id = $idPath[1];
           if ($id) {

               $imgPath = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$this->_entityResource->getAttributeRawValue($id, 'image', Mage::app()->getStore());

           }
       }

   }

   return $imgPath;
   }
   ```
4. Updated below code of `category/widget/link/link_block.phtml`

   ```
   <?php
   $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
   ?>
   <span class="widget widget-category-link">
     <a <?php echo $this->getLinkAttributes() ?>>
   <span><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAnchorText()) ?></span>
   <img src="<?php echo $this->getImage();?>" />
    </a>
   <br/>
   </span>
   ```

Hope it will help!